# How does the Macbook Pro 2021 M2 cool itself

Tags: macbook-pro

It seems to never get hot. I do web development for work, all day, lots of servers running and like at least 100 overall spread over a few windows of Chrome tabs, lots of Desktop space things too. My other Acer - you can hear the fans and it gets hot to touch underneath. But the Macbook NEVER seems to get hot, AT ALL. Maybe warm? I don't hear any fans either. And it seems like it's OK to use it directly on the bed (no airflow).

I don't game on it ever. (Work laptop)

Comment: There’s a new cooling design and obviously improved CPU efficiency, but from the few details you supplied, you don’t seem to be taxing it all that much.  That said, a [quick internet search](https://medium.com/illumination/how-to-solve-overheating-issue-of-macbook-m1-pro-and-m1-max-15d055d17bca) shows there are overheating issues with this generation. Can you edit with a better idea of what you’re running on both machines so we can get a better idea of your environment for comarison?

Comment: Apple did not make a MacBook Pro M2 in 2021.

Comment: The real question is "why do Intel CPUs generate so much heat?" Apple Silicon is a new design, from the ground up, without all the layers and complexity of the Intel CPU. It has been proven to be much more thermally efficient: it uses less power, and turns less of it into heat.

Comment: Thermal paste near the CPU (which emits lots of heat) conducts the heat away. Also, M2 (and M1) MBPs use active cooling systems that pull in cool air and eject hot air.